# BCP CHAR value to Snowflake

Tags: mysql, sql, padding, bcp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a BCP file with | delimiter and then load it to a snowflake table.

Issue:
in SQL server there are columns defined as CHAR(4) and have values "sss"
so when i do BCP the its being padded to length of 4 "sss " and being loaded to snowflake 
due to which our reports are failing because they do something like where column="SSS" but due to trailing space in snowflake the correct columns are not showing up.

we do not want to change our reports. So, is there a way that BCP can handle the padding or trimming of these columns?

note that there 24 tables and each have around 130+ columns so i cant go and put Trim functions on each char column

Comment: How about defining the type to be `varchar(4)` in either SQL Server, Snowflake, or both?

Comment: Is your question that the trailing space is not being included in the BCP file, or that Snowflake is removing the trailing space when it is loaded into Snowflake?

Comment: This turns out to be a problem because of Snowflake CHAR semantics differing from other databases.

Comment: Should the title of this be something like...  "BCP adding spaces to data before load into Snowflake"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, is there a way that BCP can handle the padding or trimming of these columns?

Yes, but not by some switch or option. The correct way to handle this is to set your datatypes up front. As someone mentioned in comments to your question, your query that is creating BCP output should use VARCHAR(4) instead of CHAR(4). BCP is giving you what you asked of it. They way to avoid whitespace is to use varchar.

Seems like a fairly quick "find and replace" against scripted out query objects would work fine but you know your situation best.

Additionally, "trim" wont work - FYI. Even if the value of the field was only "SSS" (as in your example); if the result/column is defined as CHAR(4) you will get 4 bytes of data and a blank in the 4th place since you only had 3 bytes of data. Trim will work during the query... the padded " " you are getting is placed there by the copy out. The way to correct this is to set your data types as you need up front.

Unless someone knows of a better way in snowflake (im not familiar with it) the only other option is to manipulate the file inbetween SQL and Snowflake. replace " |" with "|"... but... blech.

Comment: Redefining datatypes may be an option for a small homegrown solution, but not for most.  You're right that BCP queryout trim() probably won't work (not without a cast to VARCHAR), but the more elegant workaround would be to use the TRIM_SPACE option to COPY INTO as Mike Walton suggests in his answer.

Comment: The data types can be set with DDL or just by casting in a view/query that actually queries the data. This can be done in a homegrown or enterprise solution. In fact, i find it's much more likely in the enterprise solution where you more than likely have direct access to source data. But agreed, if there is a quick clean way to handle this at the destination, then do so. I am addressing the posters question about SQL Server BCP directly.

Answer (score 2):

If your BCP file is maintaining the trailing space, then Snowflake will retain it, too, as long as the field is being FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY a " or '.  You may also want to make sure your TRIM_SPACE option is correctly set on your format definition for your COPY INTO command.

If your BCP file isn't maintaining the space and you can't figure out how to get that to work, you could force the space back in during the COPY INTO command with some string functions in your SELECT, or you could create a view for your report that does the same set of string functions to force the space for your report to work from.

Comment: BCP is maintaining the trailing space, which it should.  Using TRIM_SPACE should be a nice way to fix the report problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known "issue" with `BCP`.  The "solution" is to use the `queryout` option, which means you must include a query with every export.  But the data are the way they are.

Eg: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/88c258fe-d1a6-4f3a-9dac-40388d04e9c7/remove-space-in-columns-on-bcp-out?forum=transactsql

But this is really a Snowflake problem, because Snowflake has its own default `CHAR` semantics.
You get a warning in the documentation [String & Binary Data Types](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/data-types-text.html) but that doesn't tell the whole truth.

The following executed on Oracle (and apparently MSSQL? MySQL?) will select the `aaa` line:

```
CREATE TABLE C AS SELECT CAST('aaa ' AS CHAR(4)) t FROM DUAL;
SELECT * FROM C WHERE t = 'aaa';
```

but won't on Snowflake, unless you create the column with `COLLATION`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE C (t CHAR(4) COLLATE 'en_US-rtrim');
INSERT INTO C VALUES('aaa ');
SELECT * FROM C WHERE t = 'aaa';
```

Unfortunately, you can't `ALTER` the collation after creation, which would have been convenient after a `COPY INTO <table>`.

**PS:** Mike Walton's answer is better, `TRIM_SPACE` is much cleaner than `COLLATE`.

Comment: This is not an "issue" with BCP.  The type is `CHAR()`.  `CHAR()`s are padded with spaces.

Comment: I agree, hence my quotes. It's about default CHAR semantics being different on Snowflake.

Comment: the issue the poster is having is not "aaa "... his value is "aaa". His issue is that he copy out is forcing 4 bytes of data... not that an extra byte is actually included in the data. It's hard to fault Snowflake here when the real value is "aaa" and not "aaa ". It's a delimited file... there is no need for fixed width fields.

Comment: The values are the same in _both_ databases, and that is 'aaa '.  The two databases behave differently, the comparison 'aaa ' = 'aaa' returns TRUE in the original database, but FALSE in Snowflake.  But when configuring COLLATE for the Snowflake column, 'aaa ' = 'aaa' returns TRUE in Snowflake also.  A second option is to trim strings when importing into Snowflake, and hope this doesn't break something else.

Comment: original poster states...  have values "sss" so when i do BCP the its being padded to length of 4 "sss ".... source database has only 3 bytes of data. the 4th is introduced by the copy out. The two databases DO behave differently as you say... im not addressing that. Just trying to emphasize that it's the copy out that is introducing the byte because of the choice of data type. The data itself is fine.

Comment: The original poster says his original column is CHAR(4), and this mean that even if he executes UPDATE .. SET my_column = 'sss', the string gets space-padded to length 4.  This happens in most databases, but _not by default in Snowflake_, and that may create an issue when porting to Snowflake. If Snowflake had default rtrim collation of CHAR data like other databases do, there would be no porting issues.